# How can I create a 10x12 grid of plots in R?

Tags: r, plot, shiny, shinyapps

I am working on a Shiny project, and I want a figure that displays 120 plots under one arrangement. I tried using `par(mfrow=c(10,12))`, but it returns an error message stating `Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large`. Is there an alternative function I could use? (The plots are not constructed in `ggplot2`, they were made using the R-base graphing functions.

Comment: The use of `par(mfrow)` was sufficient to assume base graphics, as `ggplot2` (and `grid`-based graphics in general) do not honor it. The only way to deal with that is to control the margins around the plot regions by using `par(mar=)`. One may also choose to reduce point/test size (`cex=`) or line width (`lwd=`), though that won't eliminate the error. Bottom line, this is sensitive to the overall canvas size, which (1) we don't know here, and (2) changes between your dev environment and between different users/browsers.

Comment: as a website, the canvas width is 1500px and the canvas height is functionally infinite if that helps

Comment: I can reproduce a 10x12-panel plot with no error and default values (not changing `mar`gins), starting with a device 1500px wide and 1250px tall. (I did this with both a local device (regular R plot window) and with `png(...)`.) This suggests to me that either (1) your width is not 1500px, or (2) your height is not what you think it is. Can you provide a minimal reprex?